# Здесь нужны "запятая и тире"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Единственное место, где можно купить корабль, -- эта гавань."

Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

В предложении, под словом "эта", подразумевается указание на определённую гавань.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единственное **место**, где можно купить корабль, ― эта **гавань.**

Знаки препинания расставлены верно: **тире** ставится между группой подлежащего  и группой сказуемого, связки нет. Определение "эта" входит в состав сказуемого, придаточное относится к подлежащему и **обособляется запятыми**.

Можно для ясности добавить слово-связку "вот": Единственное  место, где можно купить корабль, ― **вот** эта гавань.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая безусловно нужна, но не соглашусь с аргументацией **Матвея Дёмина**: по правилам русского языка перед частицей ***это***, связывающей подлежащее и сказуемое, тире также обязательно, они никак не взаимозаменяемы. «*Единственное место, где можно купить корабль, — это эта гавань*».